# Data truncated for column 'CODE' at row 1 in mysql for Load Daya Query

Tags: mysql

Below is the query which am trying to execute in mysql

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'E:/sakthi.csv'
INTO TABLE vwbmp.vw_province
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(CODE, NAME, LANG_CODE, DELETE_FLAG,UPDATE_TIME);
```

but I got the below error message..please correct me where I went wrong.

> Data truncated for column 'CODE' at row 1 Row 1 doesn't contain data
>   for all columns Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns Row 1
>   doesn't contain data for all columns Row 1 doesn't contain data for
>   all columns

Comment: all values got inserted into CODE Column like 81, '11000,dsd,', '', '', , ''

Comment: Can you publish a few lines of your csv file and the table definition?

Comment: If `81, '11000,dsd,', '', '', , ''` got inserted into your first column, then your fields are probably not terminated by `\t`, but e.g. `,`.